# Как задать .htaccess для подкаталога

Tags: .htaccess

у меня есть сайт(на котором размещается портфолио), и мне нужно задать для каждого подкаталога собственный htaccess, который будет управлять этим подкаталогом. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: что значит управлять? ограничение доступа, редирект?

Comment: сделает игдексным файлом index.php, который лежит в этом подкаталоге